# Broken Pipe during push - Github issue

Tags: github, pipe, push

I'm new at version control using Github. Everytime I try to push files to a repository i created, i receive the following log:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push -u --recurse-submodules=check --progress
"origin" refs/heads/bruno.peixoto:refs/heads/bruno.peixoto
Counting objects: 1481, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
FATAL ERROR: Network error: Software caused connection abort
fatal: sha1 file '' write error: Broken pipe
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:brunolnetto/Semestres.git'
Done
```

I've followed the beginners instructions but it seems it's not a naive error i'm stumbling at. Attention to the last 5 lines! It happens either if I try to a small project or a big one. I'm struggling with this issue for a couple days and looked for the solution in numerous forums, however without success . Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: Do you have access to a VPN or another network? I personally have received this error just recently. Something is wrong on my network and I cannot upload large files. If I connect to a VPN or use a different ISP, it works. Give that a try if you can. At least rule out the network being the problem.

Comment: @Recognizer Thank you for the answer. I've solved the problem but not "conventionally": instead of looking for the problem specifically, I have simply created another repository and transfered all the files to it, something similar to the "turn on and off" solution of IT professionals. It worked and that is what matter. I hope this answer may help other comrades with the same issue. Hehe.